# Linux NUKE_PATH Environment Variable only regonized in GUI / Interactive

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables, centos-7, rendering

I have set the "NUKE_PATH" environment variable which is recognized and loads without issue when running nuke from an open terminal but when I submit a remote render job using RUSH, it is being ignored.

Even running Nuke in -V verbose mode from the terminal shows where it loads the environment variable and looking at the logs, that's being skipped when submitting remotely.

I have set the NUKE_PATH in the following 3 places:

- /etc/environment (NUKE_PATH=/path/to/scripts)
- ~/.bashrc (export NUKE_PATH='/path/to/scripts')
- ~/.bash_profile (export NUKE_PATH='/path/to/scripts')

None of these are being recognized with a command line execution of a render but all work fine in the GUI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further experimentation, I found the best way to handle this wasn't at blade level in linux but rather at submission level with python.  Setting ENV as part of the process with:

- os.environ["NUKE_PATH"] = "/path/to/scripts"

fixes the problem and handles it in a more controlled and efficient way while also saving the hassle of having to set ENV on any of the host machines no matter what OS it is.